Why the polyfit second coefficient is not zero?
I have this class exercice and I have a question regarding the second coefficient given by the polyfit function.
Python code:
import numpy
X = [1,2,3,4,5]
Y = [1,2,3,4,5]
function = numpy.polyfit(X, Y, 1)
display(function)

Image with the execution of the code below:


because floating point arithmetic is not exact, this is virtually equal to zero

Also see: is floating point math broken?

@mozway although what you say is true. I am slightly surprised that numpy does not get that particularly simple integer problem exactly. Evidently numpy.polyfit does not test the hypothesis that setting a coefficient very close to machine epsilon to zero might improve the fit (or warn about overfitting). FWIW Excel's LINEST does a worse job with m2 ~ 3.83e-16 but their polynomial fit inside charts gets it exactly right (that code was always good up to cubics). Some polynomial fitting codes polish their raw answer to avoid having the OP's question asked.
